# Animate scrollTop on a div with overflow while using waypoints

Tags: jquery-animate, viewport, scrolltop, jquery-waypoints

I want to have a div with automatic scrolling content when the user scrolls to that point in the website.

It's like this example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/bLcnx/11/)

```
$("#div").animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 2000);
```

With this above example the scrolling happens immediately when the page loads.

My div with the scrolling content is further down on my site, so I want it to automatically scroll when it hits that waypoint. (I'm using jquery-waypoints in my page already).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this scroll animation to happen when `#div` hits the top of the window:

```
$('#div').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 2000);
});
```

You may want to use that `direction` parameter to do something different if its value is `"up"`. You may want to use `triggerOnce: true` to just do the animation once and then never again. It's up to you.